# How to extract text from td node using Selenium and Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I need to get the text of a td element with selenium. I have problem with extract text, I just receive null. I tried used list, `getText()` and so on. The HTML code is on the picture and element looks like you can see on the picture.

```
getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"standortTable\"]/tbody/tr/td[2]")).isDisplayed();
String test = getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"standortTable\"]/tbody/tr/td[2]")).getText();
System.out.println(test);
```

But I receive NULL, just "".

[image]

Comment: if you right click in the td element in developer tools and go Copy -> Copy XPath is the path the same is in your code above?

Comment: Try with this xpath once - `//table[@id='standorteTable']/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]`

Comment: Screenshots of the UI are great, screenshots of code or HTML are not. Please read why [a screenshot of code/HTML is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code/HTML and properly format it instead.

Comment: Are you sure the HTML you've posted matches the location in the DOM from the screenshot? The HTML shows a table and the Standort section of the picture doesn't look like a table. I also don't see the field label "Standortname" that should be beside the "Teststandor1" value in the field. A link to the page would be really helpful here.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are missing a wait I.e. you trying to read the element text content before it is completely rendered.
Try this:

```java
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(getDriver(), 30);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//table[@id='standortTable']//td[@aria-colindex='2']")));
String test = getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//table[@id='standortTable']//td[@aria-colindex='2']")).getText();
System.out.println(test);
```

Answer (score 0):

The element is an [Angular](https://angular.io/) element, so to extract the text ***Teststandort1*** you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the `visibilityOfElementLocated()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *xpath* and `getText()`:

  ```
  System.out.println(new WebDriverWait(getDriver(), 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//table[@id='standortTable']//tbody//tr[@class='ng-star-inserted']//td[@aria-colindex='2']"))).getText());
  ```
- Using *cssSelector* and `getAttribute("innerHTML")`:

  ```
  System.out.println(new WebDriverWait(getDriver(), 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("table#standortTable tbody tr.ng-star-inserted td[aria-colindex='2']"))).getAttribute("innerHTML"));
  ```